# What is the use of the following?

Tags: magento-1.9

Go to System ->Configuration

On left hand side select General -> Web and under that you will find the Search Engines Optimization tab

Use Web Server Rewrites => No

Answer (score 0):

> URL rewrites make it possible to make existing URLs more “search engine friendly” and also easier for humans to read. Enabling Web Server Apache Rewrites is part of the initial Magento setup. Magento routinely uses URL rewrites to remove the file name “index.php” that normally appears in the URL just after the root folder. When Web Server Rewrites are enabled, the system rewrites each URL to omit “index.php.” The rewrite removes words that convey nothing of value to search engines or customers, and has no impact on performance or site rank.

https://docs.magento.com/m2/ee/user_guide/marketing/url-rewrite-configuration.html

Not really necessary for SEO, but does make a cleaner URL.  If you site is already in the serps, I wouldn't change it